# Sum of 2 distinct counts: 4 counts total

Tags: sql, count, sum, distinct, concatenation

I am stumped here, and please tell me if i am spinning in circles/confusing.

I want the distinct count of conact(buisness unit/master/primary supp) where sch = bb  distinct count of conact(buisness unit/master/primary supp) where sch = zz then total those two columns.and a total count of concat master/business unit/primary supplier/sch type in zz,bb

here are the two from tables
[tbl1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAPKe.png)

[tbl2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVEka.png)

here is my desired output:
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f68fq.png)

i have been trying a multitude of queries to try and get this output but nothing is working for me. beginner struggles :(

Comment: Thanks for the question. It might help to provide some more context: What programming language are you working with (I am guessing SQL)?
Also your question is pretty difficult to read as it appears to be a mix of sql-snippets and your actual question. It might help to improve the formatting of your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (in particular "syntax highlighting for code" can be achieve using 3 backticks before and after the code).

Comment: sorry, yes SQL Server Management Studio. i will compose one of my hopeful error queries to make it more readable